# select list allowed value

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have this code to create a select list in drupal dynamically.

```
$res = db_query("select field1 from content_type_1");
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
$rows[] =$row['field1'];
}
return $rows;
```

output is like:

```
<select>
<option value="0">row['field1']</option>
</select>
```

i need output like this

```
<select>
<option value="row['field1']">row['field1']</option>
</select>
```

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about it, but I suppose that drupal :

- uses the key of the array for the `value` attribute,
- and uses the value of the array as content of the `<option>`.

If it's the case, changing your loop to this could help :

```
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)){
    $rows[ $row['field1'] ] = $row['field1'];
}
```

Now, for each item of the `$rows` array, the key is the same as the value.

Comment: Great :-) Glad I could help. Have fun !

Answer (score 1):

To be "drupal compliant", your code should follow the "drupal way" of writing SQL query.

You need to use {...} around the name of the SQL table (this allow drupal to add a prefix if needed), and you should use

```
$res = db_query("select field1 from {content_type_1}");
while ($row = db_fetch_array($res)) {
  $rows[] =$row['field1'];
}
```

Then, for any form on the site, you should use the **[form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6)** (**[select](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#select)** statement)

So the code should be something like :

```
function mymodule_form(&$form_state) {
  $form['mySelect'] = array(
   '#type' => 'select', 
   '#title' => t('A title'), 
   '#default_value' => '',
   '#options' => get_rows();
  );
  return $form
}

function get_rows() {
  $res = db_query("select field1 from {content_type_1}");
  while ($row = db_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rows[] = $row['field1'];
  }
return $rows; 
}

/* .. more code if needed .. */
// Then you can print your form.
// This should be called by a hook_menu or a theme() function ... not alone like here.
echo drupal_get_form('mySelect');
```

Comment: thank you. i dont need a form. i have  a content type and it has a select list field. i used allowed values and php code to do this.

Answer (score 0):

now sure, but most of my selects from databases look a log like this:

```
<select name="cctype">
    <option value="" selected = "Selected" >Pick one</option>
<?PHP
while($row = db_fetch_array($res)) {
    echo (' <option value="'.$row["field1"].'">'.$row["field1"].'</option>');
}
?>
</select>
```

hope that helps.

Silver Tiger

Comment: drupal php code need to return a array. look my code. thank you.